# Codeception with docker compose in Symfony: 'No route found'

Tags: php, docker, symfony, docker-compose, codeception

I'm trying to integrate the codeception framework into my symfony 4.4 app in docker. I have `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: '2'

services:
    application:
        build:
            context: .
        volumes:
            - ./entrypoint.dev.sh:/init/entrypoint.sh
            - ./:/var/www/app/
        env_file:
            - ./env/app.env
            - ./env/mysql.env
            - ./env/nginx.env
        working_dir: /var/www/app
        tty: true
        ports:
            - 80

    nginx-proxy:
        build: docker/nginx-proxy
        ports:
          - "80:80"
        volumes:
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro


    #...
    # other services
    # ...

    chrome:
        image: selenium/node-chrome:4.4.0-20220812
        shm_size: 2gb
        depends_on:
            - selenium-hub
        environment:
            - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
            - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
            - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
        ports:
            - "6900:5900"
    
    selenium-hub:
        image: selenium/hub:4.4.0-20220812
        ports:
            - "4442:4442"
            - "4443:4443"
            - "4444:4444"
```

My codeception acceptance conf file `acceptance.suite.yml`

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Symfony:
            part: services
            kernel_class: Cimple\Kernel
            app_path: 'src'
            environment: 'dev'
            em_service: 'doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
        - Doctrine2:
            depends: Symfony
            cleanup: true
        - WebDriver:
              url:  http://application:80 # My app from container
              host: selenium-hub # I use WebDriver Selenium
              port: 4444
              browser: chrome
        - \Helper\Acceptance
step_decorators: ~
```

And simple acceptance test:

```
$I->amOnPage("/login");
$I->see('Test');
```

I'm running my test in `application` container `php vendor/bin/codecept run --steps`.
But I have error:

```
Fail  Failed asserting that  on page /login
--> Symfony Exception
Symfony Docs
Symfony Support
ResourceNotFoundException NotFoundHttpException
HTTP 404 Not Found
No route found for "GET /login"
```

Of cource the `login` route is exists.

I'm guessing, I have problem with the base URL for my app in `acceptance.suite.yml`, because `application` and `selenium` are in docker containers, and `selenium` doesn't see my app. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: I would probably let codeception spam me with some `-vvv` to hopefully find out what's happening

Comment: It looks like Symfony configuration issue to me.